# How to prevent dialog to open twice

Tags: android

I had button in my app, on doubleClick of my button I open a dialog. Sometimes when I doubleClick the button in a fast way then the dialog opens twice, as a result of which the user has to cancel the dialog twice.

So can anyone suggest me how can I prevent this dialog to open twice on doubleClick of my button?

Comment: why not a single click instead of double click.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be this will help you:

Take a count variable i.e., `count=0;`.
In button click validate condition such that `if(count==0)` show dialog and make count to 1. (with this dialog will not open second time) while dismissing dialog make count to 0 again.

I think this will work

Hope it helps.

Comment: count is declared as local or global variable

Comment: One more thing my dialog open twice during double click of button

Comment: but if the user dismiss the dialog without clicking ok or cancel button..just think user open the dialog and click back button..in that case the count is 1..then dialog will never appear

Comment: hey Udaykiran ur code is working fine,but in my case i dismoss the dialog on click of dialog ok and cancel button..so when sometime i dismiss the dialog on click of back button then count value still remain 1 so dialog doesnt open again but rest what u said is working fine so do u have any clue for that

Comment: Please use a boolean at least.

Comment: Thanks Che Jami..I am using boolean only.but whats make the difference

Comment: A boolean has 2 possible values - can be theoretically held in memory as 1 bit. A 32-bit integer has 2^32 possible values. Take your pick.

Comment: add a wrapper to your clickable view. something like this https://medium.com/@and_rey/singleclicklistener-debouncedclicklistener-for-android-app-1c55273fb1cf

Answer (score 16):

make a field for your dialog, like

```
private Dialog m_dialog = null;
```

and in your onClick listener check it's status:

```
if ((m_dialog == null) || !m_dialog.isShowing()){
    m_dialog = new Dialog(...); // initiate it the way you need
    m_dialog.show();
}
```

**edit**
btw, if you don't need to initialize dialog every time you may separate if() clause like this:

```
if (m_dialog == null){
    m_dialog = new Dialog(...); // initiate it the way you need
    m_dialog.show();
} 
else if (!m_dialog.isShowing()){
    m_dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The current way should be to use an DialogFragment. With that, you don't need extra code logic, if you just use your tags and skip loading if that Fragment with tag already exists:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment prev = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TAG_DIALOG");
        if (prev == null) {
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            // Create and show the dialog.
            DialogFragment newFragment = ImageDialog.newInstance(b);
            newFragment.show(ft, "TAG_DIALOG");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

When the `Button` is pressed, disable it using `Button.setEnabled(false)`. When the dialog finishes, re-enable the `Button` using a `DialogInterface.OnDismissListener`. This way you don't have to hold a global reference to your dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You should create dialog variable before onClick.
For example:

```
private fun onFilterClick() {
    val dialog = FilterDialogFragment()

    btn_filter.setOnClickListener {
        if (!dialog.isAdded)
            dialog.show(supportFragmentManager, dialog.tag)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a DialogFragment you can also use the isAdded property

```
if (dialog?.isAdded == false)
        dialog?.showNow(fragmentManager, MyFragmentDialog.TAG) // or parentFragmentManager if you open it from another fragment
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem for last 2 days and after a lots of hit and trial I found a small problem in my code that **I was not dismissing the dialog** which I opened in onPostExecute() of my AsyncTask to do some extra work after AsyncTask Work.

When I called `myCustomDialog.dismiss()` everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean isBusy = false;

View.OnClickListener ShowDialog_Click(){
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(isBusy){
                return;
            }
            isBusy = true;
            //show dialog
        }
    };
}

dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
          dialog.dismiss();
          isBusy = false;
      }
});
```