# Different behaviours of AlertDialogue between a rooted Transformer tf 101 and a Samsung Note 2 and Samsung Galaxy Tab

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

So, I have a simple thing of code:

```
private void promptToZap() {
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which) {
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                startProgressBar(20);
                break;

            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                gotoGrassLoop();
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    overlay.setProgress(0);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("CI is yellow, would you like to zap?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener).setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
}
```

which is only called only once from a method that's called only once.

On the Transformer it works fine. It prompts once, it processes the users choice perfectly fine.

On the Note 2 and Galaxy Tab, it prompts twice.  Then when you select options from it, it does the result twice.

So, general questions....

Is their a way to check if an AlertDialog is already being displayed?

or

How can I make it only prompt once and not twice?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, should have Google'd a bit more than what I did.

But solution is similar to: [How to prevent dialog to open twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527296/how-to-prevent-dialog-to-open-twice)

I just used a boolean, isDialogShown and checked if it was false before calling .show(), then setting it to true after the .show(), then in the buttons/case(switch) statement, reset it to false.

This worked for my purposes.